# Yii sql generation

Tags: php, sql, yii

I am trying to prepare the following sql query but unfortunately it did not work.

```
select course.course_name, enroll.start_date from dp_courses course LEFT OUTER JOIN dp_enroll enroll ON course.id = enroll.course_id and enroll.student_id=3

$criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
            'order'=>'update_time DESC',
            'with'=> array('enroll'),
        ));
    $criteria->alias = 'course';
    $criteria->together=true;
    $criteria->join='LEFT OUTER JOIN dp_enroll ON dp_enroll.course_id=course.id and dp_enroll.student_id='. Yii::app()->user->id;
            //$criteria->condition='dp_enroll.student_id='. Yii::app()->user->id;
```

relation in the course model is:

```
 public function relations()    { 
    return array(
                    'enroll'=> array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Enroll', 'course_id'),
                    'author' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'YumProfile', 'author_id'),         );  }
```

but the resulting sql query what i want

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dp_enroll enroll ON course.id = enroll.course_id **and** enroll.student_id=3
```

joining tables on two attribute with the **and** operator

Comment: What means _"did not work"_?

Comment: if u don't understand the question then it dosen't mean you down grade it. I want to generate the SQL line 1 above snippet. with the help of cdbCriteria.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. I wasn't the down-voter to prove that I will add my -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is in docs, point 1 **Declaring Relationship**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship). Yii does not have idea about composite join in your example. If you want join like this, you have to define composite key relation, instad `course_id` define with array it like stated in docs:

```
array('fk_c1'=>'pk_c1','fk_c2'=>'pk_c2')
```